# How safe is SSH?

Tags: security, ssh

I wonder how safe ssh is, espespecially in state of authentification/initializing. Is there any way for a hacker to sniff some "hashkeys" or stuff to decrypt my stream? or is SSH completly safe, with no yet known bugs or weaknesses?

I read some text on that topic, but almost all of them dont cover such special cases. at best they only tell to use ssh instead of telnet

thanks

Answer (score 2):

SSH-1 is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

SSH-2 *can* be vulnerable but usually only if you're accepting dodgy third party public keys, or not patching known implementation bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of the asymmetric encryption used in ssh nothing transmitted over the wire can be used to decrypt your communication.

If you re only trusting the correctly signed public keys and using SSH-2.